# Conventions for Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, notation, curvature

I am aware of two conventions for the Riemann curvature tensor, namely the expression
$$\langle\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z,W\rangle$$
is either declared to be $R(X,Y,Z,W)$ or $R(W,Z,X,Y)$.  These differ by a sign.  A reason to prefer the first convention is that the order of $X,Y,Z,W$ is preserved.  A reason to prefer the second convention is that the expression for the sectional curvature makes more sense: $R(a,b,a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ form an orthonormal basis of a plane inside the tangent space.  Are there other reasons to prefer one of these conventions over the other?  What is the history of these two conventions?  Why these and not any other orderings of $X,Y,Z,W$ (the second convention has a somewhat bizarre ordering, so I wonder if there's a specific reason for it)?

Comment: Wild guess: the slots for X and Y are kept next to each other as either the first two or the final two due to the obvious antisymmetry between those two slots. The pairwise symmetries (X,Y) <-> (Z,W) of the Riemann tensor means we want to place (X,Y) either in the first two or the final two slots to emphasize this symmetry. Finally, before the use of invariant notation when everyone uses coordinate indices, it is easier to remember the meaning of $R^i_{jkl}$ if $i$ is the "extreme" index (first most or final most).

Comment: Note also, that O'Neill, for example, writes $$ R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_{[X,Y]} Z - [\nabla_X, \nabla_Y] Z $$ which is in some sense an ordering that you didn't list.

Comment: I usually see $R(X,Y,W,Z)$ instead of $R(W,Z,X,Y)$.  One reason to prefer this is seen in Penrose's abstract index notation, where
$$ \nabla_i \nabla_j Z^k - \nabla_j \nabla_i Z^k = R_{ij}{}^k{}_l Z^l . $$
This one naturally expresses the Riemann curvature tensor as an $\mathrm{End}(TM)$-valued two-form and also preserves the order of the indices.  If you lower the index, this recovers your display as $R(X,Y,W,Z)$.

Comment: I prefer strongly defining the operator $R(X,Y) = [\nabla_X, \nabla_Y] - \nabla_{[X,Y]}$ mentioned by @WillieWong, and writing $\langle W, R(X,Y)Z\rangle$. It removes all ambiguity from the order of the vector fields. If I want to write the components of the tensor with respect to an orthonormal basis, then I write $R(e_k,e_l)e_j = R^i{}_{jkl}e_i$, and $e_i\cdot R(e_k,e_l)e_j = R_{ijkl}$. The reason I like this is that the skew symmetric pair of indices matches the pair of vector fields $X$ and $Y$ with respect to which the curvature tensor is explicitly skew symmetric.

Comment: On the other hand, it is all too easy to forget what exactly $R(X,Y,Z,W)$ means.

Comment: @WillieWong Besides O'Neill, there is also the Book Einstein Manifolds of Arthur L. Besse.

Comment: @WillieWong, why is the convention you mentioned not the same as R(W,Z,X,Y)? I mean Why is not W(R(X,Y)Z)=R(W,Z,X,Y)?

Comment: @ProphetX Algebraically if you impose the rules $R(X,Y,Z,W) = R(Z,W,X,Y) = - R(Y,X,Z,W)$ then you can certainly classify the conventions into one of two classes based on sign. But _notationally_ I would argue that defining $R(X,Y,Z,W)$ to be $\langle \nabla_X\nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y\nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z,W\rangle$ versus $\langle  \nabla_Z \nabla_W X - \nabla_W \nabla_Z X - \nabla_{[Z,W]}X,Y\rangle$ are two different definitions, even though they end up equivalent.

Comment: @ProphetX so my point was that O'Neill takes a different convention for the curvature operator. In Deane's comment and in the original question the curvature is computed with $[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$, while O'Neill's book uses the opposite $\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z - [\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]Z$. This is relevant to the original question because in the OP it is stated that $R(X,Y,Z,W)$ is preferred by the OP because "the order of $X,Y,Z,W$ is preserved". I was pointing out that even the preference for that form of the curvature operator is a convention itself.